# Page is not redirecting in reactjs but browser URL changes

Tags: reactjs

I have below `react-js` code, which written for showing the navigation bar

When I click the links, the browser address changes BUT redirection is not happening

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import {
  HomeRounded,
  SchoolRounded,
  WorkRounded,
  Facebook,
  Twitter,
  LinkedIn,
  GitHub,
  Telegram,
} from "@mui/icons-material";

import { Link, NavLink, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import resumeData from "../../utils/resumeData";
import CustomButton from "../Button/Button";
import "./Header.css";

const Header = (props) => {
const pathName = props?.location?.pathname;
console.log(pathName);

return (
<Navbar expand="lg" sticky="top" className="header">
  <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/">
    <Navbar.Brand className="header_home">
      <HomeRounded />
    </Navbar.Brand>
  </Nav.Link>

  <Navbar.Toggle />
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <Nav.Link
        as={NavLink}
        to="/"
        className={pathName == "/" ? "header_link_active" : "header_link"}>
        Resume
      </Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link
        as={NavLink}
        to="/portfolio"
        className={
          pathName == "/portfolio" ? "header_link_active" : "header_link"}>
        Portfolio
      </Nav.Link>         
    </Nav>
   </Navbar.Collapse>
 </Navbar>
     );
    };

   export default withRouter(Header);
```

Here is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {  BrowserRouter as Router,
   Switch,
   Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import {Container, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

import Profile from "./components/Profile/Profile";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Portfolio from "./pages/Portfolio/Portfolio";
import Resume from "./pages/Resume/Resume";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";


 function App() {
 return (
    <Container className={'top_60'}>
      <Grid container spacing={7}>
       <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Profile/>
       </Grid>
       <Grid item xs>       
       <Router>
      <Header/>
  
     <Switch>
         <Route path="/portfolio">
           <Portfolio />
         </Route>
         <Route path="/">
           <Resume />
         </Route>
  
       </Switch>
       </Router>
 

        <Footer/>
        </Grid>
     </Grid>
     </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It works fine ONLY when I manually click ENTER on browser URL!

here is the error in console

[image]

Comment: where Navbar  used and where are routes defined ?

Comment: what is version of your react-router-dom ?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"

Comment: no actually, I've been checking your code and everthing seems to be correct, is that possible to make codesandbox for it ?

Comment: strange, it works in the online sandbox and not working in my local browsers.  I am using Visual studio code for development.

Answer (score 0):

on app.js you have to declare the routes on this way:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Comment: no its not working